# postgresql ignores index for recursive query

Tags: postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table representing graph of hierarchy links (parent_id, child_id)
The table has indexes on parent, child and both. 
The graph may contain loops and i need to check them (or, maybe i need find all loops to eliminate them).

And i need to query all parents of a node recustively.
For this i use this query (it is supposed to be saved in view):

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursion(parent_id, child_id, node_id, path) AS (
     SELECT h.parent_id,
        h.child_id,
        h.child_id AS node_id,
        ARRAY[h.parent_id, h.child_id] AS path
       FROM hierarchy h
    UNION ALL
     SELECT h.parent_id,
        h.child_id,
        r.node_id,
        ARRAY[h.parent_id] || r.path 
       FROM hierarchy h JOIN recursion r ON h.child_id = r.parent_id
      WHERE NOT r.path @> ARRAY[h.parent_id]
    )
 SELECT parent_id,
    child_id,
    node_id,
    path
   FROM recursion
   where node_id = 883
```

For this query postgres is going to use very terrific plan:

```
"CTE Scan on recursion  (cost=2703799682.88..4162807558.70 rows=324223972 width=56)"
"  Filter: (node_id = 883)"
"  CTE recursion"
"    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..2703799682.88 rows=64844794481 width=56)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on hierarchy h  (cost=0.00..74728.61 rows=4210061 width=56)"
"          ->  Merge Join  (cost=10058756.99..140682906.47 rows=6484058442 width=56)"
"                Merge Cond: (h_1.child_id = r.parent_id)"
"                Join Filter: (NOT (r.path @> ARRAY[h_1.parent_id]))"
"                ->  Index Scan using hierarchy_idx_child on hierarchy h_1  (cost=0.43..256998.25 rows=4210061 width=16)"
"                ->  Materialize  (cost=10058756.56..10269259.61 rows=42100610 width=48)"
"                      ->  Sort  (cost=10058756.56..10164008.08 rows=42100610 width=48)"
"                            Sort Key: r.parent_id"
"                            ->  WorkTable Scan on recursion r  (cost=0.00..842012.20 rows=42100610 width=48)"
```

It seems like postgres does not understand that external filter on node_id is applied to child_id in first recursive subquery.

I suppose i'm doing very wrong thing. But where exactly?

Comment: Normally, there is a condition in the first part of the UNION: either the top node (has no parent) or the leaf node (has no children), or some specific record# that you are interested in. Your code uses *every* record as a chain-starter.

Comment: The first query of the union retrieves **all** rows of the table. No index will help with that

Comment: I hoped that postgres can merge outer filter with internal subquery. Seems like i'm too optimistic.

Comment: Postgres doesn't push conditions into the CTE in general, see e.g. [here](http://modern-sql.com/feature/with/performance) but in this case it couldn't do that anyway because to which part of the union should it apply the `where node_id = 883`? If it pushes that to both parts it would be wrong

Comment: thanks for reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to move `WHERE node_id = 883` to first part of union:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursion(parent_id, child_id, node_id, path) AS (
     SELECT h.parent_id,
        h.child_id,
        h.child_id AS node_id,
        ARRAY[h.parent_id, h.child_id] AS path
       FROM hierarchy h
      WHERE node_id = 883
    UNION ALL
     SELECT h.parent_id,
        h.child_id,
        r.node_id,
        ARRAY[h.parent_id] || r.path 
       FROM hierarchy h JOIN recursion r ON h.child_id = r.parent_id
      WHERE NOT r.path @> ARRAY[h.parent_id]
    )
 SELECT parent_id,
    child_id,
    node_id,
    path
   FROM recursion
```

Comment: In such case i cannot save the query into view, but only into function with input parameter for the starting filter.

Comment: function is parameterized view :-). And only by using where in non recursive part you can speed up your query

Comment: Yes. The function is probably indeed what i need here.

Comment: @RomanTkachuk If the path traversed is very long, this takes lot of time. I guess it is due to the fact that the path is stored as part of each row in the table. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is much more effective way to solve the graph traversing tasks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.terr_ancestors(IN bigint)
RETURNS TABLE(node_id bigint, depth integer, path bigint[]) AS
$BODY$
WITH RECURSIVE recursion(node_id, depth, path) AS (
  SELECT $1 as node_id, 0, ARRAY[$1] AS path
  UNION ALL
  SELECT h.parent_id as node_id, r.depth + 1, h.parent_id || r.path
    FROM hierarchy h JOIN recursion r ON h.child_id = r.node_id
    WHERE h.parent_id != ANY(path)
)
SELECT * FROM recursion
$BODY$
```

And similar way for descendants.

Comment: If the path traversed is very long, this takes lot of time. I guess it is due to the fact that the path is stored as part of each row in the table. Is there any workaround for this? @QwiglyDee

Comment: @CRM the path is an essential part of the data. and it is used to stop recursing on loops. if you don't need the path perhaps previous answers are more suitable

Comment: i need to ensure that already visited paths are not traversed again by the CTE hence maintaining path seems necessary for my requirement. But since the path is part of each row, it is not scaling for big traversal. So I was wondering if there is any better way of doing it @QwiglyDee

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to optimize the data structure in general - we need to track all visted nodes, and the path is in memory. Maybe, some hash-like datatype like `hstore` is more efficient to use as 'set of nodes'. I haven't tried it though.